# "a quiet head"? I need a more natural sounding equivalent

Tags: expressions

I am racking my brain for a solution to this. I am translating a text discussing a long-term project performed by a bank. In this case, the bank is very worried that it won't achieve all of the project's milestones in time. So it didn't approve any summer vacations for its employees, and it funded and created a private summer camp for their children.

The boss is now saying that the bank created this camp so that the employees can work "with a quiet head" (that's the literal translation - I need something more idiomatic. The basic idea is that the workers will be able to focus on their work without having too many other problems or distractions to deal with...).

Any creative suggestions are more than welcome!
Ilan

Comment: *Undistracted by family matters*? This is more directed to the specific situation than perhaps you are looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So that the employees may work through the summer with **peace of mind**.

This assumes, of course, that the bank isn't holding the children hostage in the camp pending the successful completion of the project.

Comment: Wow - I think you hit the nail on the head! Thank you!

Comment: +1 But I think the more common form is *having* peace of mind, rather than *with* ...

Comment: @Ilanysong I'm not sure hitting nails on the head will give you peace of mind :)

Comment: I think 'peace of mind' means an emotional freedom, such as from anxiety or worry, more than the absence of distractions, other obligations, or various things that demand mental attention. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peace+of+mind . This may or may not mean what OP wanted.

Comment: "Peace of mind" is perfect for this context. Normal English speakers will understand, implicitly,  that it means so the workers can focus on work with out the distractions of kids and summer vacations, when used in context. To say "clear mind" or "with out distraction" will likely upset some workers.

Comment: "So that the employees may work through the summer with peace of mind." means to me that the bank knows they are screwing me over and are trying to compensate. While "So that the employees may work through the summer with a clear mind." means I should be working anyway but I complained too loudly, so to shut me up, here have this, and now go back to work.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for one word I'd say serenity or tranquility.

If you're looking for a fairly literal approximation, "a clear head" is common enough in English.

Answer (score 1):

The expression [take your mind off (somebody/something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+mind+off) may fit in the context:

> - to cause you to stop thinking about who or what is causing worry.
>
>   - *That's the good thing about helping other people – it takes your mind off your own problems.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

- The fact that the bank will take care of the children will allow employees to take their minds off, be more relaxed and focuc on their activities.

Comment: Hmm... I've certainly heard of "taking their minds of something" - but doesn't that require an object? Can you just "take your mind off", without specifying what it is that you're taking your mind off of?

Answer (score 1):

The bank [put their fears to rest](http://www.gymglish.com/www/backoffice/vocabmodule/putmyworriestorest-translation/english-lessons).

Comment: The bank employees fear their own children?!? I can see this being a type of _putting their minds at ease/rest_, but there is no fear involved anywhere.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: perhaps they fear the children will have no supervision? "Fears" synonymous with anxiety or concern in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a common phrase that expresses this sentiment exactly, so I think you can construct something like "free to focus (on work)". [Here's](http://www.neiu.edu/financial-aid/northeastern-voices/free-focus-school) an example specifically regarding a student not worrying about financial aid.

Other suggestions, such as "peace of mind" or "putting fears to rest" mean more an absence of emotional turmoil. If you want to indicate that employees are free from distractions rather than distressing emotional states, don't use those phrases.